# How can I add a .dot file as a macro button in Word 2013?

Tags: vba, user-interface, ms-word, ribbon, word-2013

I have a macro that I have coded in a VBA module, saved in a .dot file. However, when I go to Customize Ribbon in Word and try to add it, it does not show up. I have tried saving it in the Word STARTUP folder as well as the Custom Office Templates folder.

I would like to have the macro set up so that it loads in all Word Documents as a clickable button on the Word toolbar/ribbon.

Comment: Just to check the basics: In the "Customize Ribbon" dialog, under "Choose commands from," are you looking in the "Macros" category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you for `dotm` files.  I think it should work the same for `dot`.  However, you might as well switch to `dotm` since you have Word 2013.

1. Exit Word.
2. Put the `dotm` in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\Startup`.  You mentioned you have already done this, which is good!
3. Restart Word.
4. Check File | Options | Add-Ins and make sure your `dotm` is listed under "Active Application Add-ins".

   - If not, hit "Go" at the bottom to manage "COM Add-ins," and hit the checkmark by your `dotm`'s name.
5. Right-click the ribbon and select "Customize Ribbon."
6. In the "Customize Ribbon" dialog, under "Choose commands from," select the "Macros" category.

   - All your macros should be listed there, *by project name*.  You may have to hunt through the list as they will all start with `Project.` by default.  You can change your project's name in the VBA editor, Properties pane, to make it easier to find.
7. Choose the destination and hit `Add>>`.

Tested in Word 2013, Windows 8, with numerous `dotm` files.

Comment: I switched to dotm, which worked on my test machine, thank you for the detailed instructions!